# Python SQLAlchemy: Mapping a PostGIS geom field

Tags: postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, postgis

SQLAlchemy maps DB columns to object members in Python. [For example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html):

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(12))
```

Which type should be used to map a [PostGIS geom column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71779/972) to a class member?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built in way to do this with SQLAlchemy. However, [GeoAlchemy2](https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy2) is an extension to SQLAlchemy that adds support for geospatial fields (points, lines, polygons, etc):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Sequence
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(12))
    geom = Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

GeoAlchemy2 also provides functionality for spatial queries. From the [docs](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.4/orm_tutorial.html#spatial-query):

```
query = session.query(Lake).filter(Lake.geom.ST_Contains('POINT(4 1)'))
```